# Please can "how-can-i-write-to-the-buzz-controllers-...-to-work-LEDs" be reopened for answer

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

The OP in the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230399/how-can-i-write-to-the-buzz-controllers-hid-device-created-by-hid-sony-c-to-work) had tried various methods to WRITE to the HID device (Sony Playstation "Buzz" controllers) but had not had any success - including via a shell script.  I too had been trying on and off for a couple of years and recently I found out that I could do so easily with a simple script and perhaps due to changes that had already been incorporated in the GNU/Linux kernel that were not, I think present, when I first tried many moons ago.

As the question has been "closed as off-topic by jasonwryan, Gilles, cuonglm, chaos, garethTheRed Sep 18 at 6:56" and my standing on U&LSE is not high enough I cannot post an answer even though it and the question would fall within the remit of on-topic questions as listed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the Meta SE, specifically in the area of "Shell scripting".

Though the second half of the OP's question is not relevant I was reluctant to suggest an edit that would remove the material (if only to show all the things the OP had tried) - I did suggest a change to the title (which WAS accepted) to make it seem less like a C coding question.

tl;dr;

Please can this question be reopened so I can post a valid, on-topic, answer (and try for my "Revival" or "Necromancer" badges!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went ahead and reopened it. I can't guarantee it will remain that way since the original question was indeed more of a programming issue than *nix so I won't insist if others vote to close it again.

Still, having a shell-based answer sounds useful so let's see how it goes. Go forth and claim your badges!